# Retrieving json object into xCode comes with a nil value always

Tags: php, json, swift

I am just trying to get this json connection with my sql. The php file is working fine. Is writes and retrieves when I test it directly.

But on XCode I can only write. When I try to get the json object back it always come back as a nil. The error goes bellow. Any idea what could that be?

> NSURLSESSION error - nil 
>   NSURLSESSION data - <0a0a3264 36663234
>   37323334 37383135 65313633 33653764 30383233 34626231 34346262
>   61653830 3637436f 6e6e6563 74656420 746f2064 61746162 6173656c
>   6f63616c 686f7374 6c6f6361 6c686f73 74537769 66744170 707b2273
>   74617475 73223a22 34303022 2c226d65 73736167 65223a22 506c6561
>   73652063 686f6f73 65206469 66666572 656e7420 656d6169 6c206164
>   64726573 73227d>
>
> JSON dictionary - nil
>
> json error - Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7f8e88a44d40
>   {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and
>   option to allow fragments not set.}

```
import UIKit

class SignupViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var userEmailAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userRepeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userFirstnameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userLastNameTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }


    @IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        let userEmail = userEmailAddressTextField.text
        let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text
        let userPasswordRepeat = userRepeatPasswordTextField.text
        let userFirstName = userFirstnameTextField.text
        let userLastName = userLastNameTextField.text

//        if (userPassword != userPasswordRepeat){
//            
//            self.displayAlertMessage("password do not match")
//            
//        }
//        
//        if (userEmail.isEmpty || userPassword.isEmpty || userFirstName.isEmpty || userLastName.isEmpty){
//            
//            self.displayAlertMessage("All fields required")
//            
//        }


        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/SwiftAppAndMYSQL/scripts/registerUser.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)

        //let postString = "userEmail=\(userEmail)&userPassword=\(userPassword)&userFirstName=\(userFirstName)&userLastName=\(userLastName)"

        let postString = "userEmail=8&userPassword=90&userFirstName=890&userLastName=809"

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

             println("NSURLSESSION error - \(error)")
             println("NSURLSESSION data - \(data)")

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
            {

                if error != nil {
                self.displayAlertMessage(error.localizedDescription)
                return
                }


                var err:NSError?

                var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

                println("JSON dictionary - \(json)")
                println("json error - \(err!)")
                println("JSON data - \(data)")


                if let parseJSON = json{


                    var userId = parseJSON["userId"] as? String

                    println(userId)


                    if (userId != nil){

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(
                            title: "Bam!",
                            message: "Registration Sucessful",
                            preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                            title: "OK",
                            style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){
                            (action) in

                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                        }

                        alertController.addAction(okAction)

                        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }

                    else{

                            let errorMessage = parseJSON["Message"] as? String
                            if (errorMessage != nil){
                                self.displayAlertMessage(errorMessage!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

        }).resume()



    }


    func displayAlertMessage (message: String){

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Bam!", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(okAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

Php script i am using

```
<?php

//use MySQLDAO;

require ("../db/MySQLDAO.php");
$config = parse_ini_file('../db/SwiftApp.ini');

$returnValue = array();

if (
        empty($_REQUEST["userEmail"]) ||
        empty($_REQUEST["userPassword"]) ||
        empty($_REQUEST["userFirstName"]) ||
        empty($_REQUEST["userLastName"])) {

    $returnValue["status"] = "400";
    $returnValue["message"] = "Missing required information";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);

    return;
}

$userEmail = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userEmail"]);
$userPassword = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userPassword"]);
$userFirstName = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userFirstName"]);
$userLastName = htmlentities($_REQUEST["userLastName"]);

$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$secure_password = sha1($userPassword . $salt);
//http://localhost/SwiftAppAndMYSQL/scripts/registerUser.php?userEmail=email&userPassword=123456&userFirstName=gui&userLastName=Maia
echo $secure_password;

//CONNECT USING .INI
$dbhost = trim($config["dbhost"]);
$dbuser = trim($config["dbuser"]);
$dbpassword = trim($config["dbpassword"]);
$dbname = trim($config["dbname"]);
$dao = new MySQLDAO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);  

$dao->openConnection();

echo $dao->dbhost;
echo $dao->dbname;

$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($userEmail);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
    $returnValue["status"] = "400";
    $returnValue["message"] = "Please choose different email address";
    echo json_encode($returnValue);
    return;
}

$result = $dao->registerUser($userEmail, $userFirstName, $userLastName, $secure_password, $salt);

if ($result) {
    $userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($userEmail);
    $returnValue["status"] = "200";
    $returnValue["message"] = "Sucessfully registered new user";
    $returnValue["userId"] = $userDetails["user_id"];
    $returnValue["userFirstName"] = $userDetails["first_name"];
    $returnValue["userLastName"] = $userDetails["last_name"];
    $returnValue["userEmail"] = $userDetails["email"];

} else {
    $returnValue["status"] = "400";
    $returnValue["message"] = "Could not register user with provided information";
}

$dao->closeConnection();

echo json_encode($returnValue);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in string format was:

```
2d6f2472347815e1633e7d08234bb144bbae8067Connected to databaselocalhostlocalhostSwiftApp{"status":"400","message":"Please choose different email address"}
```

Which is not a valid JSON structure. You have to get only the part surrounded by the `{}` (and including those `{}`) before you can cast it into JSON dictionary.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, but not sure if I understood it. Would mind to elaborate it a bit? Which part of the code I should change?

Comment: There are strings before the `{`, make it non-JSON format. You have to make sure your data is a valid  JSON data object in order to cast it successfully.

Comment: You just need to make sure the PHP side responds with a valid JSON data or you filter it within the application using Objective-C. Both ways are fine.

Comment: Thanks Zhi, Is there any example you know I could have a read on? Specifically on how to format this data on a way xcode could read? I am extremely lost in this one.

Comment: Just added the Php script I am using

Comment: I'm no PHP expert but as far as I can see there's nothing that will result in the prefix string chunk. You can make substring from `{` on then load it make it into data before casting to JSON dict.

Comment: Finally got what you mean. Thanks Zhi! Was a lame newbie error... well... learning.